# How to properly use tail to concatenate all hidden files

Tags: filesystems, cat, tail, head

**Issue**

I want to be able to :

1. concatenate all files in a directory (regular and hidden),
2. but I would also like to display the title of each file at the beginning of each concatenation.

I found some solutions on the web, where I can do #2 with `tail -n +1 * 2>/dev/null` super neat trick, but it doesn't include hidden files like if I were to do: `cat * .* 2>/dev/null`  or even `head * .* 2>/dev/null`

The cat command will do the trick but doesn't include the filename, and the head command will not print/concatenate the whole contents of each file.

**Question**

Is there a way to do what I need to do with `tail`, *if not what is a good substitute to achieve the same result/output.*

**Update with an example**

The tail command when attempting to concatenate all files (regular and hidden)

```
[kevin@PC-Fedora tmp]$ ls -la
total 8
drwx------   2 user user 4096 Jun 23 09:24 .
drwxr-xr-x. 54 user user 4096 Jun 23 08:21 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 user user    0 Jun 23 09:24 .f1
-rw-rw-r--   1 user user    0 Jun 23 09:24 f1
-rw-rw-r--   1 user user    0 Jun 23 09:24 .f2
-rw-rw-r--   1 user user    0 Jun 23 09:24 f2
-rw-rw-r--   1 user user    0 Jun 23 09:24 .f3
-rw-rw-r--   1 user user    0 Jun 23 09:24 f3
-rw-rw-r--   1 user user    0 Jun 23 09:24 .f4
-rw-rw-r--   1 user user    0 Jun 23 09:24 f4
-rw-rw-r--   1 user user    0 Jun 23 09:24 f5
[user@PC-Fedora tmp]$ tail -n +1 *
==> f1 <==

==> f2 <==

==> f3 <==

==> f4 <==

==> f5 <==
[user@PC-Fedora tmp]$ tail -n +1 * .*
==> f1 <==

==> f2 <==

==> f3 <==

==> f4 <==

==> f5 <==

==> . <==
tail: error reading '.': Is a directory
[user@PC-Fedora tmp]$
```

Comment: Is there a problem with `tail -n +1 * .*`? You've tried that with both `head` and `cat`, why not `tail`? Is it that you sometimes only have one file so you don't get the file name?

Comment: Yes, let me update the question with an example.

Comment: Yes, good find @StephenKitt. Rennitbaby, you can just do `tail -n +1 * .[^.]*`, which is basically explained in the suggested duplicate. If that works for you, please accept the duplicate suggestion.

Comment: That solved the issue, beautiful find @StephenKitt. And thank you @terdon for the help! I think from the look of it `head` and `tail` process arguments is different, hence `.[^.]*` regex is needed to match hidden files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zsh` and GNU `tail` (not all tail implementations can take more than one filename arguments, and not all that do will display the file names):

```
() { (($# == 0)) || tail -vn +1 -- "$@" < /dev/null; } *(ND)
```

`-v` is to still print the filenames even if there's only one file, `D` for dotglob, `N` for nullglob, using an anonymous function which is passed the expansion of that glob and checks for the special case of the current directory being empty.

`</dev/null` is to partly mitigate the fact that GNU `tail`, when passed a filename called `-`, will read stdin instead. Here, we just prevent it from reading stdin, but it still won't read the file called `-`. Another approach would be to use `"${@/#%-/./-}"` in place of `"$@"` to replace `-` with `./-`, but that would also mean that you'd see `==> ./- <==` instead of `==> - <==` for the `-` file (still probably better than `==> standard input <==`).

You may also want to add the `.` (or `-.`) glob qualifier to restrict to *regular* files only to avoid the errors or worse if there are directories or other types of non-regular files in the current directory (`*(ND-.)`).

Same with `ksh93` and GNU `tail`:

```
(
  FIGNORE='@(.|..)'
  set -- ~(N)*
  (($# == 0)) || tail -vn +1 -- "$@" < /dev/null
)
```

Same with `bash` and GNU `tail`:

```
(
  setopt -s nullglob dotglob
  set -- *
  (($# == 0)) || tail -vn +1 -- "$@" < /dev/null
)
```

Or with GNU `tail` and any POSIX `sh` (including `zsh`, but only in `sh` emulation), also restricting to regular or symlink to regular files and replacing `-` with `./-`, but potentially processing the files in  a different order as we're doing `.*` ones before the other ones:

```
(
  set --
  for file in .* *
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    [ "$file" = - ] && file=./-
    set -- "$@" "$file"
  done
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || exec tail -n +1 -- "$@"
)
```

Or you could use GNU `awk` (here with `zsh`):

```
() {
  (( $# == 0 )) ||
    gawk 'BEGINFILE{
            print sep "==> "substr(FILENAME, 3)" <=="
            sep = "\n"
          }
          {print}' "$@"
} *(ND-.)
```

`awk` has the same problem as `tail` with `-` and also with filenames that contain `=`. We work around both by adding that `./` prefix which we strip upon display. Note that awk adds a newline character if missing at the end of the files.

Or use a loop:

```
sep=
for f (*(ND-.)) {
  print -r "$sep==> $f <=="
  sep=$'\n'
  cat < $f
}
```

(`cat` has the same problem with `-`, which we work around by passing the file on stdin instead of arguments)